# Using DefaultNewFormUrl's link on Document Library opens item on save

Tags: list, document-library, list-view, splist

As our company tries to move away from the folder structure and into a tag-driven structure we were left with a dilemma. Users can only add content to folders/libraries yet they don't want to have to navigate to these libraries to add content.

That said, we've built an Application Page that runs through a user's rights and allows them to add an item to any list they have access to -- linking them through `list.DefaultNewFormUrl`. This works for the majority of our lists, except document libraries. While a user can upload a document and fill out the form when they press the `Save` button SharePoint tries to open that document.

We have `Open new form in a dialog` set to off for all of our libraries and during my investigation I realized that *no matter what* SharePoint opens `Upload.aspx` (the first step in creating a new item for a document library) in a dialog. What's more, the link uses a JavaScript method `NewItem2` which then opens the form in a dialog and does something incomprehensible to me.

**My question is**

Why on earth are users being prompted to open the file they just added to the library when the new form is accessed outside of the list view page? Any ideas, or potential fix ideas?